# How to build a portion of Android source in Android Studio without cloning entire android library?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-source

I am trying to better understand a portion of the Android source code.

But instead of just reading it, I'd like to have it in Android Studio and be able to modify it and re-build, run it, etc.

In the past I have done this by simply copying the Java file/s in question from the source code into Android Studio one-by-one, renaming them and changing their package name to my own... and fixing any broken dependencies.

This way of doing things has worked for simple classes such as [RadioButton.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/RadioButton.java), but the "portion"/module I'm trying to "import" now is [all the files in the tts package](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/speech/tts).

So, I found [TextToSpeech.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.java) online, copied and pasted it into Android Studio, renamed it MyTTS.java and changed the package name to mine... and started going through the "unresolved symbols" and repeating the process as necessary...

But, since this tts package is much "deeper" in the Android code tree, I've run into several obstacles with resolving the broken dependencies (non-public components, aidl files, annotations, and more!) which I could just ask individual questions for, but before I try that, I was wondering if there is already some established way to do this that doesn't involve importing the entire Android library into Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is to clone the Android Source code repository, limiting what you download and then using the idegen.sh command to generate an Android Studio project which will give you full access to the source from within Android Studio.

To clone the minimum amount of Android Source, make sure you specify a specific branch to the repo command, limit the git depth to 1 and specify a [git partial clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone). These will speed up your clone, but it still will take some time.
E.g.

```
$ repo init --depth=1 -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-9.0.0_r46 --partial-clone
...
$ repo sync -j 4
...
```

Once that's downloaded, you can run the idegen.sh command to generate your Android Studio project file:

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh
...
$ lunch aosp_x86-eng
...
$ mmm development/tools/idegen/
...
$ development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
...
```

You'll then find the Android Studio project files at the top of the AOSP tree. Note that indexing will take a long time to complete each time you open the project.